# How to Query this in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have question about querying. I need to sum total of admin per account that active / logged less than 15 days from now. The problem is one account can have many admin and on admin table have "last login" field with date.

So we want to get is all admin that not logged for less 15 days from now.. so if one of the admin logged in 15 days from now will not count...

Example:

```
Account Table

id |  Account name
------------------
1  |  Tiger company
-------------------
2  |  Bear Company

Admin Table

id | Account ID | admin name  | last login
-------------------------------------------
1  |     1      | Billy Tiger | 09-01-2018
2  |     1      | Shirley     | 09-22-2018
3  |     2      | John Bear   | 09-06-2018
4  |     2      | Kyle Bear   | 09-08-2018
```

So based on above data if today 09-26-2018 then I need to get the total number per account and sum it that the admin per site is not or never login below 15 days from 09-26-2018 which is below 09-11-2018, so if one of the admin is logged will be not counted.

So from the example above.. what I want to get the total sum is "1" so basically per account.. hy "1" because the tiger company admin...t he "shirley" has been logged on 09-22-2018 so it's active... so not counted it and the Bear company none of the admin logged after 09-11-2018 so it count as 1...

I hope it example explains it well.. sorry for being all confusing.. is it possible to do that in one query? and like select sum(id) as 'total' ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sub-query , you want to filter those account who's any id login last 15 days so 1st i find those id who login with in last 15 days and filtered then count according to `accountid`

```
 CREATE TABLE `Account` (
  `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  `Accountname` varchar(25) NOT NULL
);


       CREATE TABLE `Admin` (
      `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      `Account_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Admin_Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `Last_Login` date NOT NULL
      );

  INSERT INTO Account 
  VALUES (1, 'Tiger Company'), (2, 'Bear Company');
  INSERT INTO `Admin` 
  VALUES (1, 1, 'Billy Tiger', '2018-09-01'),
  (2, 1, 'Shirley', '2018-09-22'),
  (3, 2, 'John Bear', '2018-09-06'),
  (4, 2, 'Kyle Bear','2018-09-08' );

 select t1.Account_ID
 ,a1.Accountname,
 count(distinct t1.Account_ID) as total from    
    ( 
        select a.*  from Admin a 
          left join
           (
            select distinct Account_ID from Admin
            where Last_Login>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
           ) t on a.Account_ID=t.Account_ID
           where t.Account_ID  is null
    ) t1 join Account a1 on t1.Account_ID =a1.id group by t1.Account_ID,a1.AccountName
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=baa13620bccbf6a70f6e0fc7d6e8d199

```
Account_ID  Accountname        total
2           Bear Company         1
```

Comment: Hi Zaynul Abadin Tuhin thank you for the reply! i think yes..that the answer..i need to learn more about your query..but the result that what i want too..thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry i just found not valid..how about if all last login is not in criteria...let say all last login is prev month...it still show..even show all...thanks

Comment: @user1400140 i made my query according to your sample data and it works for that if anything else you need that was not pointed on your problem description tnaks

Comment: @user1400140 you can provide your samples where you faced problem

Comment: @user1400140 in that case output will be both Tiger Company   and bear company right?

Comment: @user1400140 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9938ba9d71f0dcaa2e2aef181def897 like this right?

Comment: yes i think correct..my apologize..i got hard day..thank you i think your answer is already correct! thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Easiest and probably the most efficient way at scale would be to use a JOIN between the two tables:

```
SELECT `account`.`id`, `account`.`Account name`, COUNT(1) as 'Active Admins'
FROM `admin`
JOIN `account` ON `account`.`id` = `admin`.`Account_ID`
WHERE `admin`.`Last_Login` >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -15 DAY)
GROUP BY `account`.`id`
```

Result:

```
| id |  Account name | Active Admins |
|----|---------------|---------------|
|  1 | Tiger Company |             1 |
```

<sup>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aa745/8)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the response..but what i need the result is "Bear Company" because on Bear Company none of admin that logged after 09-11-2018 sorry if i am not explain well..thank you